# Java: Volatile variable not updating (get and set methods not working)

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronization, shared-memory, volatile

I have a Runnable "`NanoClock`" class which keeps updating a private volatile double value in its `run()` method.

This class also has a `getTime()` method which returns the double value. Another class ("`Master`") is constructing the `NanoClock` class and creates a thread, as well as calling the `start()` method.

After it did this it calls the `getTime()` method several times (with a delay), but the value is not updating. What am I doing wrong?

**NanoClock.java :**

```
public class NanoClock implements Runnable {
    private volatile boolean running;
    private volatile double time;
    public NanoClock() {
        time = System.currentTimeMillis();
    }
    @Override
    public void run() {
        running = true;
        while(running) {
            try {
                if(System.currentTimeMillis() > time) {
                    time = System.currentTimeMillis();
                }
              //This returns the updated value continuously when commented out
              //System.out.println("Time: " + String.format("%.6f", unix_time));
                Thread.sleep(2000);
            } catch(Exception exc) {
                exc.printStackTrace();
                System.exit(1);
            }
        }
    }
    public double getTime() {
        return time;
    }
    public void end() {
        running = false;
    }
}
```

**Master.java:**

```
public class Master {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            NanoClock nClock = new NanoClock();
            Thread clockThread = new Thread(new NanoClock());
            clockThread.setPriority(10);
            clockThread.start();
            //MY_ISSUE: This returns the same value every time
            for(int a = 0; a < 10; a++) {
                System.out.println("Time: " + nClock.getTime());
            }
            //MY_ISSUE: This cannot stop the while loop - I tested it with 
            //the println in the NanoClock class.
            nClock.end();
            System.out.println("Done!");
        catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.exit(1);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You always set running to true inside run method, so your while loop will never stop...

Comment: What do you think `new NanoClock()` does?

Comment: @home But the run method is only called once, right? So it should turn running to true and then stay in the while loop until I change the value of running to false, which results in finishing the method and ending the thread... Or is the run method being called continuously by itself?

@SotiriosDelimanolis I thought `new NanoClock()` calls the class constructor and creates an instance of the objet which I can then transform to a Thread. I have seen this practise several times already... Is there something wrong with it?

Comment: @AlpayY: of course you're correct. I did not properly read the whole code...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've got **two** instances of `NanoClock`:  one of them is an anonymous `new NanoClock()` which, as the `Runnable` in your other thread is happily keeping time in the backgound; the other is `nClock`, which is sitting idly by in the foreground in your main thread.

`nClock` *should* have been the `Runnable` in that other thread:

```
Thread clockThread = new Thread(nClock);  // not new NanoClock()
```

This may not be the entire solution, but it should be a big step in the right direction.

Comment: That was it, thank you!!! Sometimes you're just blind... This helped me out a lot, thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

`System.currentTimeMillis()` returns a long, but you store it in a double, which causes a loss of precision. When you change the member time (and also the return type of its getter) to a long you should get the expected result.

As a rule of thumb: When working with time units long is most appropriate datatype most of the time. Floating point numbers are not suitable to store precise results.

Comment: Initially this line of code did something else. It converted the time to unixtime format so I need the decimals. This has not been the issue however, when using the println method in the NanoClock I got the right results. My problem is, that run() doesn't update the volatile time variable.

Comment: @AlpayY This may be part of the problem, because when you compare the current time to your time variable an implicit cast happens. And I'm not sure your condition works out as you expect it to. There are also other issues with your code as others pointed out. So my post may only be a minor part of your problem.

Answer (score 0):

If the code below will take 2 seconds, then the time will change.

```
//MY_ISSUE: This returns the same value every time
for(int a = 0; a < 10; a++) {
    System.out.println("Time: " + nClock.getTime());
}
```

However a for loop with 10 iterations and a system.out will not even take a millisecond so it will not change.

Why 2 seconds? because you have a Thread.sleep in your runnable code.

```
Thread.sleep(2000);
```

Which means, the next update will be in 2 seconds.

And use System.nanoTime() instead of System.currentTimeMillis() since you really wanted nano time not millis.

---

Updated:

In my machine

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
    long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
    for(int a = 0; a < 10; a++) {
        System.out.println("Iterating " + a);
    }
    long end = System.currentTimeMillis();
    System.out.println("Start = " + start);
    System.out.println("End   = " + end);
}
```

Result, there is no difference in the start time and end time

```
Iterating 0
Iterating 1
Iterating 2
Iterating 3
Iterating 4
Iterating 5
Iterating 6
Iterating 7
Iterating 8
Iterating 9
Start = 1499592836298
End   = 1499592836298
```

That code block executed so fast that it did not take even a single millisecond. Depending on the timing, it may take 1 millisecond.

Changing it to System.nanoTime()

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
    long start = System.nanoTime();
    for(int a = 0; a < 10; a++) {
        System.out.println("Iterating " + a);
    }
    long end = System.nanoTime();
    System.out.println("Start = " + start);
    System.out.println("End   = " + end);
}
```

Result, there is a difference in the start time and end time.

```
Iterating 0
Iterating 1
Iterating 2
Iterating 3
Iterating 4
Iterating 5
Iterating 6
Iterating 7
Iterating 8
Iterating 9
Start = 1012518090518837
End   = 1012518091012960
```

Comment: Thank you, I seem to have done that mistake when I posted the question... I removed the sleep in the run() of NanoClock and added a Thread.sleep(2000) to the for loop. But I always get the same value, so the issue still persists.

Comment: Again, the for loop will not even take a single millisecond.

Comment: Thanks, the visualization was very useful! Even though my issue lied in the two instances of NanoClock existing simultaneously this was also a mistake I made when trying out different ways of testing the NanoClock class.

Comment: If you really just want to see the time change in the other code do the following: In your for-loop, add Thread.sleep(100) for every iteration. In your run() method, change the Threat.sleep(2000) to Thread.sleep(10) and remove the System.exit(0) from the catch Exception. The time will be updated every 10ms, while the loop will take a total of 1000ms. You should the the time change.

Answer (score 0):

```
Thread.sleep(2000);
System.out.println("Time: " + nClock.getTime());
```

the `for` in `main()` must be `sleep(2000)`

Comment: Thanks! Sorry, I had this in my actual program. I changed this now, I removed the sleep in the NanoClock class and added a sleep(2000) to the for loop, but I still get the same double value. Every iteration.